# É possível assinar um evento de uma lib em uma requição REST e esperar pelo retorno?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Gostaria de saber se é possível assinar um evento de uma lib de terceiros, que no caso é a Microsoft.Speech.dll. Pois, na minha tentativa, não funcionou muito bem, ou seja, o reconhecimento não acontece e o evento não é disparado. Tentei usando `Task` e também sem, porém não obtive sucesso. Na verdade não sei se é possível. assinar um evento dessa forma e a requisição esperar.
Desde já agradeço pela atenção e pela possível ajuda. Segue o código.

```
    private string retorno = string.Empty;

    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var result = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var comandos = new string[] { "comando 1", "comando 2", "comando N" };
            var ci = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
            var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
            var gramatica = new Choices();
            gramatica.Add(comandos);
            var gb = new GrammarBuilder(gramatica);
            var g = new Grammar(gb);
            sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g);
            sre.SpeechRecognized += Sre_SpeechRecognized;

            sre.SetInputToWaveFile("anyWavfile.wav");
            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        });

        await Task.WhenAll(result);

        return retorno;
    }

    private void Sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        retorno += e.Result.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que você pretende fazer, não está faltando um await no `RecognizeAsync()` ou na chamada do seu `Get()`?

Comment: Acabei resolvendo deu uma outra maneira, segurando a Thread até o evento terminar. Esses métodos não aceitam await, é uma lib bem antiga. Obrigado!

Comment: Seria legal você postar uma resposta de como você resolveu a questão ou fechar a pergunta para não deixar ela aberta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a solução que apliquei

```
private string text = string.Empty;
private ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public string Get()
{
    var result = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //code...

    });

    manualResetEvent.WaitOne();   

    return text;
}

private void Sre_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    manualResetEvent.Set();
}

private void Sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    text += e.Result.Text;
}
```